# HAProxy parsing errors

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, geolocation

i have 3 servers

```
--> haproxy - server1(uk)
            - server2(ru)
```

i followed [this tutorial](http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/07/02/use-geoip-database-within-haproxy/) and created ip for ru.subnets

now in my /etc/haproxy i have these files:

```
haproxy.conf
ru.subnets
```

in my haproxy.conf:

```
frontend http-frontend
    bind  *:80
    mode http
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http

    acl blog_acl path_beg /wp-admin

    acl ru_acl  src -f  RU.subnets

   use_backend wwwru  if ru_acl
    use_backend wwwbackend if !ru_acl

    use_backend wwwru  if blog_acl

    default_backend wwwbackend
```

everything looks okay but when i try to load config file in my haproxy i get these errors:

```
[ALERT] 170/084453 (4661) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:37] : error detected while parsing ACL 'ru_acl'.
[ALERT] 170/084453 (4661) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:39] : error detected while parsing switching rule.
[ALERT] 170/084453 (4661) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:40] : error detected while parsing switching rule.
[ALERT] 170/084453 (4661) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 170/084453 (4661) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :-)

```
frontend http-frontend
    bind  *:80
    mode http
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http

    acl blog_acl path_beg /wp-admin

    use_backend wwwru  if { src -f RU.subnets }
    use_backend wwwbackend { src -f RU.subnets }

    use_backend wwwru  if blog_acl

    default_backend wwwbackend
```